# Python edhesive 10.4

Tags: python

I've tried posting this question onto other websites and I have received, lightly to say, little to no feedback that helps.
This is the question at hand: [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwMim.png)

The code is asking to divide the numbers in a 2d array by 3, and if they're not divisible by 3, then return them to a 0 in the array.
This is the current code I have:

```
a = [[34,38,50,44,39], 
     [42,36,40,43,44], 
     [24,31,46,40,45],
     [43,47,35,31,26],
     [37,28,20,36,50]]
     
#print it
def PrintIt(x):
    for r in range(len(x)):
        for c in range(len(x[0])):
            print(x[r][c], end = " ")
        print("")



   
#is supposed to divide and return the sum. but does not
def divSUM(x):
    sum = 3
    for r in range(len(x)):
        for c in range(len(x[0])):
            sum = x[r][c] % 3
            if sum != 0:
                return 0
            return sum
     
divSUM(a)
```

The divide (divSUM) returns as nothing. and I'm unsure if numpy would work, every time I try it says its outdated so I assume it doesn't. Any help would be nice, but I'm mainly having issues with putting the undivisble by 3 numbers to a 0.

Comment: Your code won't execute more than one loop, as your return is inside the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(What I understood is that if the number % 3 == 0 you let the same number otherwise you put 0.)

I propose to work with `numpy` it's easy to do it in a simple line :

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[34,38,50,44,39], 
              [42,36,40,43,44], 
              [24,31,46,40,45],
              [43,47,35,31,26],
              [37,28,20,36,50]])

result = np.where(a%3 ==0, a, 0)

>>>result
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0, 39],
       [42, 36,  0,  0,  0],
       [24,  0,  0,  0, 45],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 36,  0]])
```

Otherwise, the problem with your code is that you wrongly choose the place where to put `return`.
So, you have to do this:

```py
def divSUM(x):
    result = []
    for r in x:
        tmp = []
        for c in r:
            if c % 3 != 0:
                tmp.append(0)
            else:
                tmp.append(c)

        result.append(tmp)

    return result
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the feedback and the code. I'll make sure to look more carefully at my returns. This helped a whole lot

Answer (score 0):

When return is run, the function is stopped. You can append all the values to a list and return that.

Try this:

```py
a = [[34,38,50,44,39], 
     [42,36,40,43,44], 
     [24,31,46,40,45],
     [43,47,35,31,26],
     [37,28,20,36,50]]
     
#print it
def PrintIt(x):
    for r in x:
        for c in r:
            print(c, end = " ")
        print()


def divSUM(x):
    sum = 3
    output = []
    for r in x:
        tmp_lst = []
        for c in r:
            sum = c % 3
            if sum != 0:
                tmp_list.append(0)
            else:
                tmp_list.append(sum)
        output.append(tmp_lst)
   return output
     
print(divSUM(a))
```

Comment: please click the checkmark if you liked my answer :)

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. The only issue I'm having now is that all of the numbers are returning back as 0. I'll continue working on it. Thank you again :-]

Comment: @01010, look at the if condition, if the sum is not 0, you append 0, but if the sum is zero, then you append the sum, maybe change this:
if sum != 0:
                tmp_list.append(0)
            else:
                tmp_list.append(sum)
to this: `tmp_list.append(sum)`